# Java-How to search an array using a thread for each row and stop all running threads if found?

Tags: java, multithreading, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to search for the first occurrence of number 0 in an array by using a thread for each row and then interrupting all threads if 1 thread found the occurrence. I read multiple questions and answers but couldn't find a simple way and I tried using a variable "found" to not run the other threads. However, it's not working and I couldn't figure out the problem. I mainly wanted to use interrupt() instead of using a variable. Any help would be appreciated.

Search class

```
public class Search extends Thread {
    int low;
    int high;
    int[][] array; 
    static int id=0;  
    private static boolean found = false;
    private boolean done = false;

    public Search(int[][] array, int low, int high) {
        id++;
        this.array = array;
        this.high = high;
        this.low= low;
    }

    public void run(){

        whileLoop:  while(!found && !done){
            for(int i = low; i < high; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
                    if(array[i][j] == 0){
                        System.out.println("Found at: "+i+" "+j + " By thread "+id);
                        found = true;
                        done = true;
                        break whileLoop;
                    }
                }
            }
            done = true;
        }
       
    }
}
```

Main class

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] array = {{3,0,2,3,0,5},{2,4,0,2,6,5},{4,1,2,4,6,5},{0,2,1,4,0,5},{4,5,6,0,7,1},{9,7,4,1,1,3}}; //6 zeros
        SearchArray searchArray =  new SearchArray();

        searchArray.sArray(array);
    }
}


class SearchArray{

    public void sArray(int[][] array){
        int noThreads = array.length;
        Search[] threads = new Search[noThreads];

        for(int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++){
            threads[i] = new Search(array, i*1 , (i + 1) * 1);
            threads[i].start();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Found at: 0 1 By thread 5
Found at: 3 0 By thread 6
Found at: 1 2 By thread 5
Found at: 4 3 By thread 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `found` variable is not `volatile`, which means that after a certain thread finds it, and this thread set `found` to `true`, and other threads cannot immediately perceive it, and they will continue to find.

But even if you set it to `volatile`, it is not enough, because multiple threads may find it at the same time.

So, if you want to strictly control only one thread will print `Found at:...`, you need to use a `lock` instead of `volatile`(lock->check->act):

```
public void run(){
    for(int j = 0; j < array[low].length; j++){
        if (found) {
            break;
        }
        if(array[low][j] == 0){
            // lock,check,act
            // if found, lock
            // array here can be a lock, since all threads share this array
            synchronized (array) {
                // check
                if (found) {
                    break;
                }
                found = true;
                System.out.println("Found at: "+low+" "+j + " By thread "+id);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, using the [`volatile`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html) keyword is necessary since you are working with variables that are shared and used by different threads.

I recommend passing only the row to the thread and not the whole array. That would not be needed. And lastly, you could use a flag to check whether an occurrence of 0 was found or not. If it is found, stop the threads.

The below example fulfills your needs.

```java
// the volatile keyword is important
public static volatile int[][] array = {{3,0,2,3,0,5},{2,4,0,2,6,5},{4,1,2,4,6,5},{0,2,1,4,0,5},{4,5,6,0,7,1},{9,7,4,1,1,3}}; //6 zeros
public static volatile boolean found = false;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) // Iterate through each row
    {
        int finalI = i;

        Thread th = new Thread() // Create a new thread for each row
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < array[finalI].length; j++) // Each thread will iterate through each element
                {
                    if(found) // If the element 0 was found, then break and stop the thread
                    {
                        System.out.println("Another thread found 0, so stopping this thread.");
                        break;
                    }

                    if(array[finalI][j] == 0) // If this is the thread that finds 0, then log and set flag to true
                    {
                        System.out.println(this.getName() + " found 0 at index " + finalI + "," + j);
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        th.start(); // Start each thread...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I didn't know about volatile, but if you could help me I actually wanted to stop all the threads once 0 is found at any row (output : found 0 at index 0,1).

Comment: They do stop right after 0 is found... Try running the code please.

Comment: I run the code it finds 0 in each row and once it finds it, it stops. How can I modify it to not even loop through the other rows if 0 is found. Like the output now is : found 0 at index 1,2, found 0 at index 4,3 ... I need only the first one

Comment: The code above finds 0 in ONLY one row and stops after it has found it. It does not find 0 on each row. Check again.

Comment: This is the output I'm getting: Thread-3 found 0 at index 3,0
Thread-4 found 0 at index 4,3
Thread-0 found 0 at index 0,1
Thread-1 found 0 at index 1,2

Comment: ```volatile``` is not enough to control ```found 0 at index``` only be printed once

Comment: `synchronized` can also be used but that is a performance penalty.